# tag html dentro de variable php

Tags: php, html

É possível eu usar tags html dentro de variable php. Por exemplo estou fazendo um loop onde eu tenho um item pai que quero que leve `<strong>` e os itens filhos eu apenas acrescento um `-`, só que se eu faço isso na hora de setar a variavel do item pai `$varPai = "<strong>{$varValue}"</strong>`, ele não me renderiza o item com strong, é possível fazer isso dentro do php?

este é o meu foreach que está montando, pai > filhos

```
foreach($listaLocalidade as $p_id => $p_nome){
$cidades = $this->Localidade->find('list',array('conditions'=>"Localidade.Localidade_id ={$p_id}", 'Localidade.programas is not null'));    
$opcoesPaisCidade[$p_id] = "<strong>{$p_nome}</strong>"; // aqui é o pai, onde eu teria que deixar strong

foreach($cidades as $c_id => $c_nome){
    $opcoesPaisCidade[$c_id] = ' - '.$c_nome;
    //die(print_r($opcoesPaisCidade));
}
```

}

E estou montando assim:

```
<select id="combobox" name="data[orcamento][localidade_id]">
  <option value="">Select one...</option>
   <?php
   foreach($opcoesPaisCidade as $p_id => $p_nome){
   ?>
   <option value="<?=$p_id?>"><?=$p_nome?></option>
   <?}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Sim, é possivel. Basta colocar entre aspas, tratando como string. No caso da tag `strong`, não seria melhor usar css para estilizar não?

Comment: então no caso, o jeito que fiz está certo?

Comment: Só agora entendi o que realmente pretendias, estilizar parte de um option está fora de questão. Simplesmente não podes.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível usar qualquer tag html numa variável php, deste que estas tags, basta que estes valores sejam impressos para o browser, para que sejam renderizados.

```
$num = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$retorno = '';

foreach($num as $numero){
    if($numero % 2 == 1){
        $retorno .= "<strong>{$numero}</strong><br/>";
    } else {
        $retorno .= "{$numero}<br/>";
    }
}

print $retorno;
```

No caso, a tag html, deve estar dentre as aspas, tanto a tag de abertura como a de fechamento.

```
$var = "<tag>{$var_a}</tag>";
```

Se for com uma lista (select), podes concatenar uma tag, com base numa condição.

```
$num = array(1,2,3);
$retorno = '';
foreach($num as $numero){
    $retorno .= "<option";
    if($numero == 3){
        $retorno .= " selected>";
    } else {
        $retorno .= ">";
    }
    $retorno .= "{$numero}</option>";
}

print "<select>";
print $retorno;
print "</select>";
```

Esta por exemplo, vai selecionar o número 3, por padrão, para deixar esse valor com negrito, podes usar uma classe e algum css, ou podes aplicar uma propriedade css em linha.

```
$num = array(1,2,3);
$retorno = '';
foreach($num as $numero){
    $retorno .= "<option";
    if($numero == 3){
        $retorno .= " class=\"bold\">";
    } else {
        $retorno .= ">";
    }
    $retorno .= "{$numero}</option>";
}

print "<select>";
print $retorno;
print "</select>";
```

Esta seria a propriedade css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bold { font-weight:bold; }
</style>
```

Ou com a propriedade css em linha:

```
...
if($numero == 3){
        $retorno .= " style=\"font-weight:bold;\">";
    } else {
        $retorno .= ">";
    }
...
```

> **NOTA:** Não é possível estilizar parte de um `option`, ou mesmo criar novas tags dentro de um, porque eles normalmente são estilizados de acordo com o plataforma em uso.

Em recomendação, existem APIs próprias para estilizar formulários, se achares que  o que estás atualemente a fazer não é suficiente, utiliza alguma API.

Comment: estou fazendo deste jeito, mas as options do meu select continuam do mesmo jeito, será que é alguma coisa do `option` que não permite?

Comment: @MichelHenriq leia os pontos que adicionei.

Comment: editei minha pergunta e coloquei como que estou montando meu foreach

Comment: Qual comando de saída estás a usar ? (print, echo, print_r, ...) ?

Comment: acrescentei na pergunta novamente.